# Redirect to Index Page if the Submitted Form Has no Username or Password

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong in this code?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["ok"])) {
    $id= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["usr"]);
    $pwd=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["pass"]);
    $row=mysql_query("select * from tbl_login where usr_id='$id' and password='$pwd'");
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($row);
    if($pwd==$data["password"]) {
        $usr=mysql_query("select * from tbl_usr where u_id='".$data['u_id']."'");
        $nm=mysql_fetch_array($usr);
        $_SESSION["usr"]=$nm["u_fname"];
        $_SESSION["id"]=$nm["u_id"];
        header("location:index.php");
    } else {
        $msg="Email Or Password not valid";
    }
}
```

And HTML code is

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
Email-Id<input type="text" name="usr" />
<br/>
    Password<input type="password" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="ok" />
</form>
```

When user clicks on the submit button without filling up the username and password, page should redirect to index page.

Comment: Can you give us the HTML code (Every thing between `<form>...</form>`) ?

Comment: could you please print out what is the contents of $pwd and $data

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
if($pwd==$data["password"]) {
    $usr=mysql_query("select * from tbl_usr where u_id='".$data['u_id']."'");
    $nm=mysql_fetch_array($usr);
    $_SESSION["usr"]=$nm["u_fname"];
    $_SESSION["id"]=$nm["u_id"];
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

since both `$pwd` and `$data["password"]` are null, it will go inside the if statement and redirect the page to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to redirect to index page or show the error message you specified in the code ? If you want to show the error message, then I guess you should echo the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["ok"])) {
$id= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["usr"]);
$pwd=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["pass"]);
$row=mysql_query("select * from tbl_login where usr_id='$id' and password='$pwd' limit 1"); // I hope you use UNIQUE or PRIMARY INDEX on usr_id 
if(mysql_num_rows($row)) {
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
    $usr=mysql_query("select * from tbl_usr where u_id='".$data['u_id']."' LIMIT 1");
    $nm=mysql_fetch_assoc($usr);
    $_SESSION["usr"]=$nm["u_fname"];
    $_SESSION["id"]=$nm["u_id"];
    header("location:index.php");
} else {
    $msg="Email Or Password not valid";
}
```

}

try it